# Is Tomcat capable of using mixed Authentication on one app (BASIC and CLIENT-CERT)?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, basic-authentication, client-certificates

Is it possible to secure resources of an web-application with tomcat (v. >6) using different auth-methods:

- BASIC
- CLIENT-CERT

I have a webapp, where some resources can be secured just using BASIC Auth. Example for Basic:

- myApp/userInterface/*

But for some resources which are exposed as services I want to use Client-Cert Authentication. Example for Client-Cert:

- myApp/api/*

Until now I have only found possiblities to do this per web-app in the web.xml but not on resource level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to configure Tomcat to do this out of the box. It might be possible with 3rd party authentication libraries.

Comment: There's a Google Code package called AuthenticRoast which provides this.

Comment: this is not true, see my anwser above.

Answer (score 0):

Me helped https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/SSLWithFORMFallback in combination with this [tomcat valve](https://github.com/encukou/pki/blob/master/base/server/tomcat7/src/com/netscape/cms/tomcat/SSLAuthenticatorWithFallback.java)  to allow SSL client certs and form and basic fallback authentication. I also adjusted it for Tomcat 8 with the adjusted authenticate interface:

```
...
public boolean authenticate(Request request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    LoginConfig config = context.getLoginConfig();
...
```

Best regards